# How to display the JSON response in 4 Sub Activities after calling Web Service from MainActivity

Tags: android, json, web-services, sharedpreferences

I have **one** Main Activity & **4** sub Activities say **SubActivity1 ,SubActivity2, SubActivity3, SubActivity4**,
I am calling the webservices from MainActivity & fetching **8** fields says **f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7 & f8**
I have to display two json response fields in each of these sub activities.
say...

SubActivity1 will display fields f1 & f2
SubActivity2 will display fields f3 & f4
SubActivity3 will display fields f5 & f6
SubActivity4 will display fields f7 & f8

kindly favor how I can achieve this functionality....can I do with **shared preferences?**

Comment: Are you `extend` SubActivities from the MainActivity ?

Comment: Sure, you could try to do it with SharedPreferences. Have you tried? Any code or want to show?

Comment: Thank you for your comment..

Comment: Yes Main Activity extends All 4 SubActivities, I don't have any code for this task, i have been told a scenario & provide the way to achieve this , any reference document kindly share...Thanks